# Entity Framework creates non-existing column in query

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, oracle-sqldeveloper, ef-database-first

I face the problem that EF creates a column in the query that does not exist in the Oracle database table.

The simplified model which is created by EF looks like this (I use DB first approach):

```
public partial class USER
{
    public int ID { get; set; }    
    public string NAME { get; set; }    
    public int PROCESS_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual PROCESS PROCESS { get; set; }
}

public partial class PROCESS
{
    public PROCESS()
    {
        this.USER = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<USER> USER { get; set; }
}
```

I set up the foreign key constraint in the oracle sql developer.

When I try to get the Users for a selected Process like this:

```
var users = context.Users.Where(u => u.PROCESS_ID == 0);
```

It produces following error:

```
ORA-00904: "Extent1"."R1": invalid ID
```

So i took a look on the produced SQL:

```
SELECT 
"Extent1".ID,
"Extent1".NAME,
"Extent1".R1,
FROM DB.USER "Extent1"
WHERE "Extent1".R1 = :p__linq__0
```

Of course this produces an error because R1 isn't a column in the table. But I can't figure out where it comes from. It seems like EF can't map the foreign key properly thats why it's also missing in the generated SQL query?

Maybe someone has a tip for me :)

Comment: EF works by conventions.   It definitely works if you used ProcessId, not sure about PROCESS_ID.  Generally, all uppercase field and property names are unconventional in C#, and CamelCase is preferred for property names, and pascalCase for fields.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the c# conventions. unfortunately Oracle makes the names uppercase. I'm just confused because in all other tables it is working expect this. and I can't figure out where my mistake is...

Comment: "Oracle makes the names uppercase" - isn't that something that should be handled by the Oracle driver, rather than something you put in your code?

Comment: I didn't put that in my code. The database table and column names are upper case and so are the class and property names in the project when they are created in the databse first approach :/

Comment: You have to add mapping configuration, either by fluent mapping of by data annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same error recently while working with Oracle using DevArt provider. Turned out it was caused by a column name being longer than 30 chars. OP mentioned that the model posted in his question is a simplified one so it still may be the case.

Answer (score -1):

To follow up my comment, here is a [link](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions) to the conventions.

> The convention for a foreign key is that it must have the same data type as the principal entity's primary key property and the name must follow one of these patterns:
>
> - [navigation property name][principal primary key property name]Id
> - [principal class name][primary key property name]Id
> - [principal primary key property name]Id

Your convention `[navigation property name]_ID` isn't on the list.

Comment: And when your Foreign Key properties don't follow the convention, you must configure them using ForeignKeyAttribute or the Fluent API on OnModelCreating.